# Graphics.paintComponents .drawString method not placing numbers on my dice roller

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a basic dice roller GUI, and I'm down to trying to get the numbers to display on the dice when I roll.  Currently everything looks right except for my dice are blank.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoller extends JPanel {

    public DiceRoller() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Dice Roller");
        frame.setContentPane(new ViewPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack(); //To set frame so contents are at or above preferred size.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ViewPanel extends JPanel {
    // Initialize the two dice
    private Dice dice1;
    private Dice dice2;

    ViewPanel() {
        dice1 = new Dice();
        dice2 = new Dice();

        JButton rollButton = new JButton("Roll");
        rollButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 30));
        rollButton.addActionListener(new RollHandler());

        JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel();
        viewPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 5));
        viewPanel.add(dice1);
        viewPanel.add(dice2);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(rollButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(viewPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class RollHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dice1.roll();
            dice2.roll();
        }
    }
}

class Dice extends JPanel {
    private String value;
    private int spot_diam = 9;

    private static Random roller = new Random();

    public Dice() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        roll();
    }

    String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        repaint();
    }

    String roll() {
        String val = Integer.toString(roller.nextInt(6) + 1);
        setValue(val);
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D eg = (Graphics2D)g;
        eg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        eg.drawString(getValue(), 40, 120);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note their is no reason apparent in above code for `DiceRoller` **or** `ViewPanel` to extend `JPanel`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));


eg.drawString(getValue(), 40, 120);
```

What are the parameters of the drawstring() method? How can you paint something at 120 when its size is only 60?

```
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
```

Don't override paintComponents() (note the "s"). It should be `paintComponent()` you override.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to override `JComponent.paintComponent()` method rather than `Container.paintComponents()` for custom painting.